# MySQL Inserting data from one table to another - error FULLTEXT index

Tags: mysql, fulltext-index

Hey guys i'm trying to create a stored procedure where I enter in the Loan_ID from my loan_table and it moves it into another table called loan_history. I'm unsure on what I'm doing wrong. The error I'm getting is 'Can't Find FULLTEXT index matching the column list'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `INSERT_INTO_lOAN_HISTORY`(in INSERT_LOAN_ID INT(11))
INSERT into loan_history
SELECT  *
FROM `loan_table`
Where MATCH (LOAN_ID) AGAINST (INSERT_LOAN_ID)
```

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE loan_table 
( Loan_ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Member_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
Item_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
Book_ID varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
Video_ID varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
Transaction_Date date DEFAULT NULL, 
Due_date date DEFAULT NULL,
etc
```

Comment: I assume you have the FULLTEXT index setup? The column list inside the MATCH function must exactly match that of the FULLTEXT index definition, unless your search in boolean mode

Comment: No I don't how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I tried this: 
    Alter table loan_table  ADD FULLTEXT index_name(loan_ID);

    but get the error loan_ID cannot be part of FULLTEXT index

Comment: `show create table loan_table` shows?

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be using MATCH. Try `WHERE Loan_ID = INSERT_LOAN_ID` in the select part of your procedure.

Comment: that worked Tristan thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other users and future reference, the solution was to remove the MATCH and change the WHERE conditional to where the ID equals the ID value from the IN parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `INSERT_INTO_lOAN_HISTORY`(in INSERT_LOAN_ID INT(11))
INSERT into loan_history
SELECT  *
FROM `loan_table`
WHERE Loan_ID = INSERT_LOAN_ID
```